# DeviceIoControl() function is working differently in Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, driver, hard-drive, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to get the Hard Disk Serial using DeviceIoControl function. And calling it with same parameters it gives different value in output buffer.

I am caliing it as

```
  if ( DeviceIoControl (hPhysicalDriveIOCTL, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                    & query,
                    sizeof (query),
                    & buffer,
                    sizeof (buffer),
                    & cbBytesReturned, NULL) )
```

where   hPhysicalDriveIOCTL = CreateFile (TEXT(deviceName), 0,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

Comment: And what is different? Do you get an error?

Comment: @SergeyPodobry I am not getting any error. The value retuned by DeviceIoControl() in "buffer" is different in win7 and win8 (I am passing same arguments in both cases). And using this value of "buffer" I have to retrieve Hard Disk Serial, so it is getting different values of same Hard Disk in win7 and wind8.

Comment: What is `deviceName`? Show us full code and output.

Comment: @Rohan
deviename is "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"